# Numerical solution to ${d\over dt} \nabla^2 p = {dp\over dx}$

Tags: numerical-methods

I need help numerically solving 
$$\frac{\partial \nabla^2 p} {\partial t} = \frac{\partial p} {\partial x}$$

I know that to solve

\begin{equation}
     \frac{\partial p} {\partial t} = \frac{\partial p} {\partial x}
\end{equation}

the finite difference formula is
\begin{equation}
     \frac{p_{i,j}^{n+1} - p_{i,j}^n} {\Delta t} = \frac{p_{i+1,j}^n - p_{i-1,j}^n} {2 \Delta x}
\end{equation}
This simplifies to
\begin{equation}
     p_{i,j}^{n+1} = r \left( p_{i+1,j}^n - p_{i-1,j}^n \right) + p_{i,j}^n
\end{equation}
where $r = \frac{\Delta t} {2 \Delta x}$, which allows me to explicitly calculate $p$ at the next time step from $p$ at the current time step.

Following the same procedure for $\frac{\partial \nabla^2 p} {\partial t} = \frac{\partial p} {\partial x}$, I get

\begin{multline}
     p_{i-1,j}^{n+1} + p_{i+1,j}^{n+1} + p_{i,j-1}^{n+1} + p_{i,j+1}^{n+1} - 4p_{i,j}^{n+1} = \\
     (1-r) p_{i-1,j}^n + (1+r) p_{i+1,j}^n + p_{i,j-1}^n + p_{i,j+1}^n - 4p_{i,j}^n
\end{multline}
where $r = \frac{\Delta \Delta t} {2}$ and $\Delta x = \Delta y = \Delta$. But now I must solve $p$ at five points simultaneously. I cannot simply march through the grid, updating each point as I go. How can I solve this equation cheaply and avoid inverting a matrix?

Comment: You could try the [Gauss-Seidel method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method).

Comment: @Winther The Guass-Seidel method would converge twice as fast as the method above. But it would still lead to a similar equation, with several terms on the left-hand side to solve simultaneously.

Comment: Is it most important that it is a fast method or an easy to implement method? How big grid / number of time-steps are you thinking about using?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fast way to solve it. Take the 2D [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) of the equation to get

$$\frac{\partial \hat{p}(\vec{k},t)}{\partial t} = -\frac{i k_x}{k^2}\hat{p}(\vec{k},t)$$

where $\hat{p}(\vec{k},t) = \mathcal{F}(p)$ is the Fourier transform of $p$. The solution of this equation is simply

$$\hat{p}(\vec{k},t) = u_0(\vec{k})e^{-\frac{i k_xt}{k^2}}$$

where I assume you have $u_0(\vec{k}) \equiv \mathcal{F}(p(x,y,0))$ as an initial condition at $t=0$. The solution in real space, at any time $t\geq 0$, can be found from

$$p(x,y,t) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left( u_0(\vec{k})e^{-\frac{i k_xt}{k^2}}\right)$$

where $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ is the inverse Fourier transform. Numerically calculating the transforms is really fast and also easy to implement if you use, for example, the [FFTW library](http://www.fftw.org/). Note that if you only want the solution at one particular time-step then this method only requires two FFTs - one to get $u_0$ and one to get back to $p$ - no matter what time you are interested in (which is for example done in milliseconds for a $50\times 50$ grid).

Answer (score -1):

Presumably you are using some boundary conditions such that $u$ uniquely determines $p$ (otherwise the problem is not well-posed). 
Since you didn't specify that, I'll assume homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions.  Solve (in a discretized version) with these boundary conditions
$\nabla^2 p = e_{ij}$ for each grid point $(i,j)$, where $e_{ij}$ is $1$ at 
$(i,j)$ and $0$ everywhere else, obtaining the Green's functions $g(x,y,i,j)$.
Then given $u$, the solution of $\nabla^2 p = u$ is $p(x,y) = \sum_{i,j} u(i,j) g(x,y,i,j)$.  Now given $p^n$, let $u^n = \nabla^2 p^n$, $u^{n+1} = u^n + (\Delta t) \partial_x p^n$, and $p^{n+1} = \sum_{i,j} u^{n+1}(i,j) g(\cdot, \cdot, i, j)$.

Comment: Are you suggestion to solve (and store the result) of $\nabla^2 p = e_{ij}$ for every grid point?